# coverage showing 100% for settings.py file

Tags: django, pytest, code-coverage, django-testing, coverage.py

I'm confused with coverage report which is generated with help of pytest. Here is my coverage html report.

[image: Coverage HTML report]

settings.py file is showing 100% covered, not sure how it is.. ?

Also, the following Loginform also shown as covered so I have added another dummy form even it is showing covered.

[image: Django form wrongly shown as test covered]

I'm facing difficulty in understanding this, though I don't have any tests added for settings or for the above forms it's showing as 100% covered, with this I'm not confident whether my code is properly tested or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coverage.py can only tell you whether a line of code has been executed.  Your form lines define a class.  Those lines are executed when the file is imported.  Coverage can't tell you whether some other code used that class or not.  Same for your settings file.  As soon as the file is imported, all of your settings assignments are executed, as coverage is telling you.  Coverage can't tell you whether a setting was used.

Answer (score 1):

[From the doc](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

> Coverage.py is a tool for measuring code coverage of Python programs. It monitors your program, noting which parts of the code have been executed, then analyzes the source to identify code that could have been executed but was not.

During the test, Django has to load the classes and other modules into the memory, and hence the program (your class and settings and many other parts) get executed.

That is, coverage is not about how much code get covered ***by your test cases***, but ***by any arbitrary command*** (here the command is *`python manage.py test`*)

IMHO, you must write separate tests for those classes ***if you have some test-cases to be covered***

Comment: the same doc mention this as well **Coverage measurement is typically used to gauge the effectiveness of tests. It can show which parts of your code are being exercised by tests, and which are not.** - so my query is not cleared as my test has not executed any code related to the above forms which I have mentioned, then how it's showing its covered..

Comment: That doesn't mean how much code gets covered by your test cases